# The parameter palletRacks cannot be changed dynamically

Tags: anylogic

I need to use the code to generate a pallet rack. When I add the pallet rack I generated to the rack system, it tells me that it cannot be added dynamically. How should I add racks dynamically using set_palletRacks(value).[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUbdk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some things in AnyLogic cannot be changed dynamically via code, this is one of them.

However, for some things (like networks), you can create it programmatically all in one go and then instantiate it, see [here](https://anylogic.help/markup/create-network-by-code.html#creating-network). Maybe there is a similar option for pallets and racks (I think there is and  I think I have done it before so worth investigating)

Comment: Thanks,I can create palletRack programmatically ,I need to add the palletRack created using the code to the parameter "Pallet racks" of the RackSystem. The RackSystem has a function named "set_palletRacks(value)",so i want to use this function to set the parameter "Pallet racks", but it will report an error,"The parameter palletRacks cannot be changed dynamically".

Comment: That is what I mean: some functions are publicly available but not supposed to be used. A good indicator is when the code-complete shows no explanatory text (as in this case).